# Can't enable Virtual Machine Platform for WSL using DISM

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-subsystem-for-linux, dism

I try to turn virtual machine by "turn windows feature on or off" but an error occurs:
[image: Screenshot]

> Error code: 0x80070490

Then, to enable WSL 2, I also try to run `dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart`, but an error occurs:

[image: Screenshot]

> Error: 1168
>
> Element not found.

This is my `dism.log` file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b7FEqS4TibXWovvC4koovqFurnKOJh75/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you on an Insider Preview build of Windows 11? Your build number seems high even for 22H2. It also seems lower than the current build I know about, my suggestion, create an ISO of the next build and perform an in-place repair install. Unfortunately due to the build number, it’s impossible to install 22H2 without a clean install

Comment: Outside of more detailed diagnostic information, I suspect it’s a [hardware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62340566/error-when-running-an-installed-wsl-platform-wslregisterdistribution-failed-wit) problem, or Windows is corrupt. Providing the .etl file might be helpful (see the appropriate GitHub issue on this error for instructions to generate it)

Comment: @Ramhound I'm using Insider Preview build of Windows 11, I try to create ISO but need to delete all system data to install next build

Comment: [My suggestion is to download the same build as an ISO](https://uupdump.net/selectlang.php?id=beae378a-c4e5-49ab-b627-afb34e680a1a) or wait till a new build is released if you are on the current build and download that ISO. Your problem likely cannot be solved without doing an in-place install